# How to convert nested Java 8 lambda to Java 1.6 compatible code?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
  private Future<?> myFuture = null;
   myFuture = executorVariable
            .submit(() -> runFuture());
```

How do I convert this to Java 1.6 code and not lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`() -> runFuture()` creates a `Runnable` that calls the `runFuture` method.

Therefore, you can rewrite it:

```
myFuture = executorVariable.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runFuture();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an anonymous runnable instance:

```
myFuture = executorVariable.submit(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        runFuture();
    }    
}):
```